# window.myFunction does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JQuery, I have a main.js file where I define my global functions, I this main.js I defined a global function

```html
window.showJsAlert = function showJsAlert (message,speed,BGcolor) {
  if (!message) { var message = 'Error# No message provided'};
  if (!speed) { var speed = 'fast'};
  if (!BGcolor) { var BGcolor = '#2ecc71'};
  if (BGcolor == 'fail') {var BGcolor = '#EA6153'};
  if (BGcolor == 'success') {var BGcolor = '#2ecc71'};
  $( "#jsDialog" ).css('background', BGcolor).show(speed);
        $('#jsDialogMessage').html(message);
 }
```

and it works perfectly fine, I can call this function from every other js file, however right next to this function I have declared one more global function:

```html
window.addLoaderIcon = function addLoaderIcon (IDofContainer) {
         if (!size) { var size = '70px'; };
         if (!color) { var color = '#926be9'; };
         if (!standard) {
          $(IDofContainer).html("<div class='text-center'><i style='color:"+color+"; margin-top: 200px; font-size: "+size+";' class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-lg'></i></div>");
         }else{
            $(IDofContainer).html("<div class='text-center'><i style='color:"+color+"; margin-top: 4px; font-size: "+size+";' class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-lg'></i></div>");
         }
 }
```

but strangely enough It doesn't work even though it is in the same js file: main.js and declared exactly as the previous one, it throws an error when I call it from another js file AND even when I call it Right after I declare it in the same js file:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addLoaredIcon is not defined

Whats going on ?

Thank You

Comment: Typo: addLoaredIcon instead of addLoaderIcon

Comment: Perhaps the reason is the typo in the code

Comment: Yes this should be `addLoaderIcon `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addLoaredIcon is not defined

You have a typo in that function, change it to addLoaderIcon and you're good to go!

Comment: Ops, that's embarrassing , Thank You ;)

Comment: Who downvoted my answer? Basically i said the same thing and someone downvoted it

Answer (score 0):

> Here you don't need to name function when you are assigning it; just `var abc = function(){ /* function code */ }` is enough; But you can use this naming for debugging;

```
 window.addLoaderIcon = function(IDofContainer) {
        if (!size) { var size = '70px'; };
        if (!color) { var color = '#926be9'; };
        if (!standard) {
            $(IDofContainer).html("<div class='text-center'><i style='color:"+color+"; margin-top: 200px; font-size: "+size+";' class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-lg'></i></div>");
        }else{
           $(IDofContainer).html("<div class='text-center'><i style='color:"+color+"; margin-top: 4px; font-size: "+size+";' class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-lg'></i></div>");
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You misspelled the function name addLoaderIcon in the code the error shows that you are trying to call some addLoaredIcon